# WinForms Application Hangs

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application (ABC) that I developed and it as a windows application (.exe). It is by itself quite a big application referring a lot of dll's.

However, now there is a requirement that demands that this application(ABC) be a part of an even larger application (XYZ). Hence, I had to change the project type of  "ABC" from being a windows application to a class library, and by changing a few lines of code.

My problem is that, ever since I started using ABC as part of XYZ, the application started hanging if I dint perform any operation on it for 10 to 15 mins... I do not have any problems while running it as a separate application.

Any reasons why this might occur?

Any suggestions would be really appreciated...

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and pausing the application to see what state the threads are in?

Comment: What does the call stack tell you?

Comment: Thanks codeka... I'm sorry, but I couldn't quite get your suggestion... Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: @Rowland : This happens when I run this application on installing it in a user's machine... But a call stack can be viewed only while debugging right (pls correct me if I'm wrong)? I haven't tried leaving it idle while debugging... I shall try that out...

Answer (score 2):

Launch XYZ in the debugger. Wait for the app to hang, pause the debugger, and have a look at what each of the threads in your process are busy with.

It might also help to turn on "break on all exceptions"

Comment: Thanks Rob... I shall try that...
But one thing : 

>>have a look at what each of the threads in your process are busy with <<

Could you pls tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Hi,
I tried leaving the app in the debugger... But while it is in debug mode (ie, when i run it in VS), the hang never happens.. However, if I install the app in the same machine that I tried debugging, the application hangs. 

So here's what I did. 
I installed the application.
Waited for it to hang.
Attached my debugger to the hung application.
Opened the Threads window and turned on Break.
I could see several threads listed.
The execution arrow pointed at one thread.
Does that mean that this thread is the one that is causing the hang?
Or have I proceeded in the wrong direction.Pls advice

Comment: Hey good thinking. No - VS can't tell you which of the threads is at fault. Go through them all and see what bits of code they're running. The ones that are running ABC or XYZ code are probably the culprits

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(VS.71).aspx) to debug the application whilst it is running on the user's machine. From your dev machine, you can attach to the process on the user's machine, and then do a debug break to see what the threads are doing.